# In Pinax/Django, how do I redirect to a link after logging in?

Tags: django, pinax

in Pinax, if I have a link that required login (i.e., I use the @login_required decorator), how do I redirect to that link after logging in, instead of being redirected to "what's next"???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set the [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#login-redirect-url) setting.

**EDIT**
It seems Pinax also supports another setting, [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/apps/account/reference/), which seems to do the same thing as LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, but is set to the url name, presumably so you don't have to make a call to `reverse` in your settings.py file.

For more 'dynamic' redirects, the [pinax.apps.account.views.login](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/apps/account/views.py#L52) view uses [pinax.apps.account.utils.get_default_redirect](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/apps/account/utils.py#L7) to look for a redirect URL from the following:

1. A GET or POST parameter named 'next' (by default, though it is possible to customize).
2. The LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting
3. The LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME setting

The code in `get_default_redirect` actually is checking in the session for a 'redirect_to' key, which presumably holds one of the values defined in the settings, as the method makes no attempt to look at `django.conf.session` on it's own. The docstring claims that it checks for those settings, however, and that seems to be what you are experiencing in your project.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Actually, my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting is set to my "what_next" named url (as per Pinax). My problem is that I am not redirected to my 'next' parameter after login, but to this "what_next" url instead.

Comment: And this happens even when my ?next get parameter is set in the login page's url. Help! Thanks!

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer - it seems Pinax 'should' be following the 'next' GET parameter. Can you confirm which version of Pinax you are using, and that you are actually using the pinax.apps.account.views.login view?

Comment: According to "pinax-admin --version", I'm using version 0.7.3, which is the latest stable, I believe. Even if I clone a fresh project (such as the social project) I get the same problem, so it has nothing to do with my project specific code.

Comment: Actually, its this line (line 20):
redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name)

in account/utils.py that seems to be giving the problem. 

when I put "print "redirect" + str(redirect_to)" just below that line, I get "None" in my output.

Comment: That's a good catch. Does the value of 'redirect_field_name' match what is actually being used in the query string?

Comment: Chris, thanks for all the help so far. The issue doesn't seem to exist in the development version of Pinax. SO I'm just gonna use that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following hidden input to you your templates/account/login.html file inside the login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
```

That should do the trick. Came up with the solution after reading the documentation found here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/